# Get bills of today's records in twilio 's Usage Record API

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I want to get the bills of lastMonth (example: for jan), in twilio  API but when i add the bills to records cumulatively, the last record gets the total bill, but it does'nt match the bill for January when i look in the 
twilio console. 
Can you see what is the actual problem?

HERE IS THE CODE:

```
const accountSid = 'your-account-sid';
const authToken = 'your-auth-token'; 
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
let cost = 0;
let  filter = {
     startDate:'2018-01-01', //for  month of january 
     endDate:'2018-01-31'  
};
client.usage.records.each(filter,record => {
    cost += parseFloat(record.price);
    console.log(cost); //last loop will show the total cost 
    // console.log('-----------');

});
```

I am using twilio 3.x for Nodejs.

Comment: Is the bill from your code more or less than reported from the console? Does this only happen for January or can you reproduce for other months too?

Comment: more than the console, if i add all the records, less than the console and if i just show the totalPrice (documentation clearly states that totalPrice may be less than or equal).

Comment: I think this needs a little more investigation and discussion than Stack Overflow provides (and I'm not sure it's exactly a programming issue). I'd recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and describe the issue to them and they will be able to dig through this or explain this to you.

Comment: yeah, but it will be a long process, anyways our project decided to took totalPrice as bill